# force compiler to fail build process when hiding method or property without "new" keyword

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Are there any settings in visual studio that enable the compiler to generate an error when a method or property hides a method or property from the base class without using the "new" keyword?

currently the compiler generates a warning

```
class A
{
  void F(){ ... }
}

class B : A
{
  void F(){ ... } //force build error because no "new" keyword is used
}
```

Thanks

Comment: StyleCop may offer you a method to do that, you can enforce style through errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into your project properties and set the radiobutton "treat warning as errors" to "all" or type the warning code you want in the dedicated textbox.

Comment: +1 I have all warnings as errors on by default, the cleaner your code is, the less likely it is to bit you in the ass later.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CS0219);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-".NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0")&rd=true

Comment: @Fabiano it's in the build output text (it will be of the form CS#### if it's from the compiler)

Comment: Thanks. I only looked in the Error List view for it.